# How to do query all points which lie on aline

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Suppose I have a set of points,

[image]

then I define line L. How do I obtain b, d, and f?

[image]

Can this be solved using kd-tree (with slight modification)?

==EDIT==

How my program works:

1. Define a set of points
2. L is defined later, it has nothing to do with point set

My only idea right now:

1. Get middle point **m** of line L.
2. Based on point **m**, Get all points in the radius of lenght(L)/2 using KD-Tree
3. For every points, test if it lies on line L
4. Perhaps I'll add colinear threshold if some points are *slightly lie* on the query line.

The running time of my approach will depend on the L length, longer the line, bigger the query, more points need to be checked.

Comment: How much do you know in advance and what do you want to be fast?

Comment: also, how is the line L defined and when?

Comment: Oh yeah, those image above are simple examples, my data actually has thousands of points.

Comment: Any chance you know the direction of the line in advance? Then you could do lookup in logarithmic time.

Comment: L is defined by start point and end point, so yes, the direction can be computed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have logarithmic-time look-up. My algorithm achieves that at the cost of a giant memory usage (up to cubic in the number of points):

If you know the direction of the line in advance, you can achieve logarithmic-time lookup quite easily: let `a*x + b*y = c` be the equation of the line, then `a / b` describes the direction, and `c` describes the line position. For each `a`, `b` (except `[0, 0]`) and point, `c` is unique. Then sort the points according to their value of `c` into an index; when you get the line, do a search in this index.

If all your lines are orthogonal, it takes two indexes, one for `x`, one for `y`. If you use four indexes, you can look up by lines at 45° as well. You don't need to get the direction exact; if you know the bounding region for all the points, you can search every point in a strip parallel to the indexed direction that spans the query line within the bounding region:

[image: strip]

<sub>The above paragraphs define "direction" as the ratio `a / b`. This yields infinite ratios, however. A better definition defines "direction" as a pair `(a, b)` where at least one of `a`, `b` is non-zero and two pairs `(a1, b1)`, `(a2, b2)` define the same direction iff `a1 * b2 == b1 * a2`. Then { `(a / b, 1)` for `b` nonzero, `(1, 0)` for `b` zero} is one particular way of describing the space of directions. Then we can choose `(1, 0)` as the "direction at infinity", then order all other directions by their first component.</sub>

Be aware of floating point inaccuracies. Rational arithmetic is recommended. If you choose floating point arithmetic, be sure to use epsilon comparison when checking point-line incidence.

**Algorithm 1**: Just choose some value `n`, prepare `n` indexes, then choose one at query time. Unfortunately, the downside is obvious: the lookup is still a range sweep and thus linear, and the expected speedup drops as the direction gets further away from an indexed one. It also doesn't provide anything useful if the bounding region is much bigger than the region where most of the points are (you could search extremal points separately from the dense region, however).

The theoretical lookup speed is still linear.

In order to achieve logarithmic lookup this way, we need an index for every possible direction. Unfortunately, we can't have infinitely many indexes. Fortunately, similar directions still produce similar indexes - indexes that differ in only few swaps. If the directions are similar enough, they will produce identical indexes. Thus, we can use the same index for an entire range of directions. Namely, only directions such that two different points lie on the same line can cause a change of index.

**Algorithm 2** achieves the logarithmic lookup time at the cost of a huge index:

When preparing:

- For each pair of points (A, B), determine the direction from A to B. Collect the directions into an ordered set, calling the set the set of significant directions.
- Turn this set into a list and add the "direction at infinity" to both ends.
- For each pair of consecutive significant directions, choose an arbitrary direction within that range and prepare an index of all points for that direction. Collect the indexes into a list. Do not store any specific values of key in this index, only references to points.
- Prepare an index over these indexes, where the direction is the key.

When looking up points by a line:

- determine the line direction.
- look up the right point index in the index of indexes. If the line direction falls at the boundary between two ranges, choose one arbitrarily. If not, you are guaranteed to find at most one point on the line.
  Since there are only `O(n^2)` significant directions, there are `O(n^2)` ranges in this index. The lookup will take `O(log n)` time to find the right one.
- look up the points in the index for this range, using the position with respect to the line direction as the key. This lookup will take `O(log n)` time.

Slight improvement can be obtained because the first and the last index are identical if the "direction at infinity" is not among the significant directions. Further improvements can be performed depending on what indexes are used. An array of indexes into an array of points is very compact, but if a binary search tree (such as a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) or an [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)) is used for the index of points, you can do further improvements by merging subtrees identical by value to be identical by reference.

Comment: Old post, but for future viewers: this solution is both extremely overcomplicated and redundant. You can achieve **constant-time** lookup with cubic memory usage very easily -- just precompute all the answers for each of the O(n^2) directions...

Answer (score 2):

If the points are uniformly distributed, you could divide the plane in a `Sqrt(n) x Sqrt(n)` grid. Every gridcell contains 1 point on average, which is a constant.

Every line intersects at most `2 * Sqrt(n)` grid cells [right? Proof needed :)]. Inspecting those cells takes `O(Sqrt(n))` time, because each cell contains a constant number of points on average (of course this does not hold if the points have some bias).

Comment: No, it's not uniformly distributed, but binning is actually a good idea, but I don't really know how to implement it

Comment: "Every line intersects at most 2 * Sqrt(n) grid cells" - that's true as long as each square is open at top and left and closed at bottom and right. It is true because of monotonicity.

Answer (score 0):

Can try the next :

1. For each point find [distance from a point to a line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)
2. More simple, for each point put the point coordinate in the line equation , is it match (meaning 0=0) than it's on the line

**EDIT:**

If you have many points - there is another way.
If you can sort the points, create 2 sort list:

- 1 sorted by x value
- 2 sorted by y values

Let say that your line start at `(x1,y1)` and ended at `(x2,y2)`

It's easy to filter all the points that their x value is not between `[x1,x2]` OR their y value is not between `[y1,y2]`

If you have no points - mean there are no points on this line.

Now split the line to  2, now you have 2 lines - run the same process again - you can see where this is going.

once you have small enough number of points (for you to choose) - let say 10, check if they are on the line in the usual way

This also enable you to get "as near" as you need to the line, and skip places where there are not relevant points

Comment: I don't want to check all of them since i have thousands of points

Comment: can you done pre-processing for the point , for example sort them by x-value and sort by the y-value ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? Why do I need to sort my point?

Answer (score 0):

- Compute the bounding box of all of your points
- Divide that bounding box in a uniform grid of x by y cells
- Store each of your point in the cell it belongs to

Now for each line you want to test, all you have to do is find the cells it intersects, and test the points in those cells with "distance to line = 0".

Of course, it's only efficient if you gonna test many line for a given set of points.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oops, you're right. I've been misled by the "uniformly distributed" part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, then it is possible to use [Hough-algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) like approach.
Fill r-theta array with lists of matching points (not counters). Then for every line find it's r-theta equation, and check points from the list with given r-theta coordinates.

Subtle thing - how to choose array resolution.